# Laravel 4: What is the replacement for Asset::add?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How do you manage assets in the new Laravel 4?  It looks like Taylor Otwell has replaced `Asset::add` with something new.

What I am trying to do is have Laravel add my CSS and JS files.  There were several ways to do this in Laravel 3, but they seem to be gone now.  One was `Asset::add` and the other was `HTML`.  What are the replacements for these?

Comment: The beta of Laravel 4 with full documentation is coming this week, just hang in there.

Comment: Good question. No documentation on ways to do this.
I've just used {{HTML::style() }} for now as a package seems like overkill.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In Laravel 4 you can use the `HTML` class, it's default included in the Laravel Framework package:

Stylesheet:

```php
{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
```

Javascript:

```php
{{ HTML::script('js/default.js') }}
```

Comment: is there no way of adding assets, from the controller when loading the view? just like it was being done in L3?

Comment: @w0rldart try `teepluss/asset` , provided [here](https://packagist.org/packages/teepluss/asset). This is a port from Laravel 3, which works flawlessly.

Comment: @w0rldart teepluss/asset doesn't work with Laravel 4.1 so I had to fork it. Please check: https://github.com/Ardakilic/laravel4-asset

Answer (score 8):

I use the helper:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-1.9.1.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

See also

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php
```

Many other helpers too, e.g. app_path(), various array tools, link_to_route(), link_to_action(), storage_path(), etc.

Answer (score 8):

Laravel 4 doesn't have out of the box asset management. But some packages have been created to handle this kind of thing.

- [codesleeve/asset-pipeline](https://packagist.org/packages/codesleeve/asset-pipeline) (my favorite so far)
- jasonlewis/basset (had some errors with this)
- teepluss/asset (closest to Laravel 3 Asset::add() but doesn't do concatenation or minification)
- way/guard-laravel (requires ruby guard gem to run)

Comment: Yea what everyone want is as many libraries as possible for so simple tasks like <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-1.9.1.js') }}"></script>. It is not a good practise how can this have 7 upvotes.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I did when I needed to append some .css and .js files only to a specific page:

In my blade template:

```
<head>
<title>.....</title>
.....
@yield('head')
</head>
```

And in my specific page blade file:

```
@extends('template')
    @section('head')
    {{ HTML::style('css/filename.css') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/filename.js') }}
    @stop
...
```

Answer (score 4):

What about Basset (former Best Asset)?: http://jasonlewis.me/code/basset

I just installed it on L4, still no tests made, but sound promissing.

Answer (score 2):

A port of Laravel 3's Asset class. Made to work with Laravel 4.

https://github.com/teepluss/laravel4-asset.git

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with Laravel 4, so I had to fork it. Please check: https://github.com/Ardakilic/laravel4-asset if you want to use it on latest Laravel projects.

Answer (score 1):

I made a much simpler version of Laravel 3 Asset class and works perfect in Laravel 4. For me it's all I need! 
Simply choose a name for the container and add the assets in the final order:

```php
Asset::container('jq_1.10')->add('js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js')->add('css/css.css');
```

For output:

```php
echo Asset::container('jq_1.10')->asset();
```

The class:

```php
class Asset {
public static $containers = array();

public static function container($container = 'default')
{
    if ( ! isset(static::$containers[$container]))
    {
        static::$containers[$container] = new Asset_Container($container);
    }
    return static::$containers[$container];
}
}

class Asset_Container {
public $name;
public $assets = array();

public function __construct($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}
public function add($source)
{
    $type = (pathinfo($source, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'css') ? 'style' : 'script';
    $obj = (object)array('type' => $type,'source' => $source);
    $this->assets[] = $obj;
    return $this;
}
public function asset()
{
    $str = '';
    foreach($this->assets as $aset){
        if($aset->type == 'style')$str .= HTML::style($aset->source);
        else $str .= HTML::script($aset->source);
    }
    return $str;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will error if you use:

```
{{ HTML::style('assets/css/style.css') }}
```

Because Laravel change Laravel Base Aliases of `HTML` to `Html`. If you got error the same me use code below to instead.

Style:

```
{{ Html::style('assets/css/style.css') }}
```

Script:

```
{{ Html::script('assets/css/style.css') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's already been answered, but Orchestra's asset package is identical to the Asset library Laravel 3 used.  Might even have been the same package. It's what I use.

https://github.com/orchestral/asset

Answer (score 0):

These dont exist in Laravel 4 - I think the idea is to use Composer bundles to add them in.

[Meido has created a 'port' of HTML, Form and Str classes from Laravel 3 to Laravel 4.](https://github.com/meido)

I'm not aware of an Asset port - I think you should view the bundles already on Composer to find one that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I just use:

```
{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}
```

Which works for all types of files. Note, it only returns the URL it doesn't return the HTML tags and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way of doing this, is with the **URL::asset()** method.

For instance:

**CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('css/style.css')}}" media="screen" />
```

or

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('js/scripts.js')}}"></script>
```

You can also use it with images and basically any asset located in your public folder.

**ie**: 
    `<img scr="{{URL::asset('img/image.jpg')}}}} id="someid">`

By using this method, i find it easier to organise and separate my HTML markup from Laravel methods.

Say if i wanted to specify a css file that is to be loaded with the media="print" attribute, the "Laravel" way of doing this is the following:

```
{{HTML::style("print.css", array('media' => 'print'))}}
```

While the conventional way, using the {{URL::asset()}} method, is more comprehensive and accessible to front end developers(Which you may be working with in a team project).

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('css/style.css')}}" media="print" />
```

You may say that the difference is minimal, but when dealing with plenty of markup attributes ("ids, data-attributes, classes custom-attributes"), the HTML::style(), HTML::image(), HTML::link() methods can turn out to be quite long, and in-comprehensive to html/css/js developers.

It all varies and depends on the developer's style of coding, but in my opinion markup should remain as "raw" as possible, so that it is more accessible to front-end developers.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use Grunt.js to manage your assets.

Grunt is basically a library of plugins that run "tasks" such as:

- Compile LESS
- Combine JS files
- Minify JS files
- Much MUCH more....

all independent of PHP.

Comment: It maybe independent of PHP, but isn't it dependent on node.js?