# php laravel blade template not rendering

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am attempting to setup a basic page using Laravel and twitter bootstrap. I installed Laravel and got the generic "you're here" or w/e image so that seems shiny.  For twitter bootstrap, I added in my /public folder the twitter bootstrap files under /resources/js, /resources/css, and /resources/img.

So now I'm trying to make a template for my views, where basically the twitter bootstrap .css files are output in my head tag and the bootstrap.min.js  and jquery.js script includes are output just before my closing body tag.

So this is what I have setup:

**laravel/app/routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
        return View::make('hello');
});
```

**laravel/app/views/hello.php**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@stop
```

**laravel/app/views/layouts/master.blade.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
    @section('head')
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    @show
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      @yield('content')
    </div>

  @section('footer_scripts')
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  @show
  </body>
</html>
```

But it the blade template doesn't seem to be rendering. This is the output I get:

```
@extends('layouts.master') @section('content')
This is my body content.

@stop
```

That's how it looks on-page as well as in the view-source. No html tag or script includes; nothing.  I must be missing something basic, and I've tried looking through the Laravel docs, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.. can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To use a blade template you must have the `.blade` in file name, for example in your case it should be

```
hello.blade.php
```

Otherwise, it won't render. Read more on [Laravel Site](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating).
Here is an example from one of my testing projects (index.blade.php), since you had a typo `@extends('layout.master')` it should be something like this

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
This is a sample of laravel 4 using blade template engine.
This is home page using HomeController and home.blade template.
@stop
```

Comment: AHA.  Actually I did try that, but it was still doing it.  I think the issue was also that at the time I had also typoed `@extends('layouts.master')` putting `layout` instead of `layouts`

Comment: @mysql_noobie_xxxx, Yes it should be `layouts`.

Answer (score 3):

on your `laravel/app/views/hello.php`

that file should have been `hello.blade.php` since you want to use blade templating engine with it.. thats it.

more information on templating can be found on the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating)

also, on the part where you declare the scripts:

```
<script src="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

it could be done using this: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205404/laravel-4-what-is-the-replacement-for-assetadd)

```
{{ HTML::script('resources/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
```

just so you know. ;)

Comment: hey thanks for the tip about the script include; this is all new to me so i've got quite a lot of stuff to learn! Sheikh was slightly quicker on the draw for answering the immediate issue so I gave him the solve, but +1 to you too :)

Answer (score 2):

Just got the same problem as described initially. But: all template filenames matches required specification with *.blade.php. Also 'layouts' pathname was set correct. Result was still no blade rendering, output was limited to `@extends('layouts.master')`.

Solution was: I've used a copy-paste view script with `<!-- app/views/index.blade.php -->` comment on the first line. Removing this comment from the template and putting `@extends('layouts.master')` on the first line of my view script instead did the trick.

Greets,
 McPan

Answer (score 2):

Hi had the same problem and i double checked my code, turns out I had omitted a $ for my variable and the page was blank couldn't be rendered, but this was with lumen, hope you can double check your code too

Answer (score 1):

place @extends() in the first line.

Comment: It would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add an explaination for your intention. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same problem, then I found, leaving a space or a line before @extends('layouts.master'), or any comments, will not render. @extends('layouts.master') should be placed at top most.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was due to space between parenthesis: instead of { {$name} }
i used {{$name}} and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and the solution is that the `@extends('layouts.master')` has to be in the very first line.