# Laravel runtime asset pipeline

Tags: laravel-4, concatenation, asset-pipeline, assets, minify

Is there any package like CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline for laravel 4 where you have:

```
-concatenation
-minification
-add resources at runtime from Views/Controllers
-adding on a file by file basis
```

Asset-pipeline is great for the most part, but the only way to add specific files is using a manifest.
You can listen for the asset.pipeline.boot event and add whole folders for the pipeline to auto load but this is not what i need.

```
Event::listen('asset.pipeline.boot', function($pipeline) {
$config = $pipeline->getConfig();

$config['paths'][] = 'some/special/javascripts'; // this must be a folder
$config['paths'][] = 'some/special/stylesheets'; // this must be a folder
```

I've also seen a previous topic very similar to this one [Laravel replacement for Asset::add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205404/laravel-4-what-is-the-replacement-for-assetadd) but they don't have concatenation of resources, are no longer maintained or have external dependencies like node/ruby and can't be used on runtime anyway.

Comment: Did you even try to look? https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline

Comment: I can't find any mention of adding resources at runtime.. the only way to add resources is with the manifest files. Thank you for not reading the entire question.

Comment: If you read above link you will see you can add paths at runtime.

Comment: You are correct for the most part, i knew about that option, but my question was asked poorly. I reformulated the question. And about your comment, yes you can add paths but not on a file by file basis and you can't really add resources from packages / views. I did read the documentation and also the issues for the project to see if anyone had the same problem as i did but found nothing about my issue. Thanks for your help.