# Laravel Error : Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception

Tags: php, laravel

I am using larval 4.2 and I am getting the following error in my wrapper.php my view file :

```
   <?php echo View::make('layouts/blocks/header')->with('sidebar', $sidebar)->with('active', $active); ?>
   <?php echo $content; ?>
   <?php echo View::make('layouts/blocks/footer'); ?>
```

Error:

```
   Error : Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception
```

Do you know whats causing this?

Comment: There's an error in one of your views.

Comment: wrapper.php is a views file , but which one you mean like the header ?

Comment: It is either in `layouts/blocks/header` or `layouts/blocks/footer`.  Comment out one or the other to pinpoint which view is having the issue, then post the contents of the view here so people can help.

Comment: Yes I know I am having an issue I have an old script using Laravel 3.2 and I am trying to move it to Laravel 4.2 its a nightmare , They user Asset::styles(); in header file I think I need to replace it with laravekl 4.2 equivalent not sure how?

Comment: http://yetanotherprogrammingblog.com/content/upgrading-from-laravel-3-to-laravel-4

Comment: Great but I don't see what he did with Asset::styles(); ?

Comment: Laravel 4 doesn't have a built in asset manager. You'll either need to install a new package and update the code to use it, or just manually write the assets into the view.  You may want to check out this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205404/laravel-4-what-is-the-replacement-for-assetadd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205404/laravel-4-what-is-the-replacement-for-assetadd).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Error: Method Illuminate\View\View::\_\_toString() must not throw an exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534016/laravel-error-method-illuminate-view-view-tostring-must-not-throw-an-excep)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel renders its views by casting an `Illuminate\View\View` object as a string.  If an object is cast as a string and has a `__toString` method set, PHP will call the `__toString` method and use that value from that as the cast value.

For example, this program

```
class Foo
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return 'I am a foo object';
    }
}
$o = new Foo;
echo (string) $o;
```

will output

```
I am a foo object.
```

There's a big caveat to this behavior -- due to a PHP implmentation detail, you can't throw an exception in `__toString`.

So, it looks like the problem you're having is something in your view **does** throw an exception. Based on the information you've provided, the error could be anything. The way I'd debug this further is to try running the PHP code in your view

```
echo View::make('layouts/blocks/header')->with('sidebar', $sidebar)->with('active', $active);
echo $content;
echo View::make('layouts/blocks/footer');
```

outside of a view (a route, a controller action, etc), making sure `$sidebar`, `$content`, etc have the same values.  This should still throw an exception, but because it's outside of `__toString` PHP will give you more information on **why** it threw an exception.  With a real error message you'll be able to address the actual problem.

Comment: I put this in my routes.php still same error and no extra error details I can't figure whats the actual issue

Comment: @user3150060 That means the error's happening in one of your sub views. Comment out the View::make lines to see if it's one, or both of the lines.  Then open the template for the `layouts/blocks/header` or the `layouts/blocks/footer` -- look for PHP code in there and repeat until you've tracked down the problem.

Comment: I noticed that adding ->render(); displayed more errors and I found out whats wrong

Comment: @user3150060 I'm not 100% sure, but I bet the View's `__toString` method definition looks something like `$this->render(...)`  By explicitly rendering the view you skipped the `__toString` step and let PHP tell you what the error was. Good thinking!